# Misconception about formulation of P=NP

Tags: number-theory

There Is a somewhat misconception i can't understand about P=NP. For example, the Hilbert's tenth problem says that we can't decide , given a diophantine Equation, if we can solve It or not. But we can clearly check that a given solution Is Indeed a solution in polinomial time. Doesn't that disprove the P=NP conjecture?

Comment: No. 1. The P=NP-problem deals only with solvable problems 2. This problem only deals with the class of NP-complete problems.

Comment: We can check a solution in polynomial time but we cannot necessarily find such a solution in polynomial time. This article possibly helps to understand the subject: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/p-vs-np-conjecture-calculations-and-meaning/

Comment: @Peter That's not actually the issue. The OP's question is real, and the answer by David Lui is correct.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the votes to close; this is a reasonable question with a meaningful answer.

Comment: Those ARE other issues since unsolvable problems can never be NP-complete and the P=NP-problem depends on the complexity of the NP-complete problems and nothing else. Problems not being in the NP-complete-class play no role for the P=NP-problem.

Comment: @Peter But the OP's point of confusion is **exactly** that they think they have an argument for Hilbert's 10th problem being in NP! The informative response is to explain, as David Liu has done, why their claim of polytime recognizability is false. Just saying "Hilbert's 10th is undecidable" won't help them: at best it points out *what* claim they're making is wrong, but not *why* it's wrong.

Comment: I completely agree with @NoahSchweber and I found the question useful. Frankly I cannot understand why the question was closed. If there was some confusion in the question is because that was the question itself. Almost any question at some point falls in this category

Answer (score 7):

You can't check solutions in polynomial time either. See the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)#Formal_definition). The solution must have length polynomial in the size of the input.  For some Diophantine equations, there is a solution but the number of digits in the smallest solution is so large that it can't be checked in polynomial time.

Comment: Nice! +1. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @lcv It follows from the unsolvability of Hilbert's 10th problem; indeed, that rules out any *computable* bound on a solution.